# Using "configurated" vs "configured"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I received an e-mail at work where someone said something along the lines of:

> "...the report was not **configurated**."

Since I've never really heard of the word they used, wouldn't it be more proper to say **configured**?

Is one preferred over the other in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They each have their own uses**, although some would argue *configure* can be used in place of *configurate* in most scenarios.

According to [MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/configurate) and [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/configure),

> #### [Configurate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/configurate)
>
> - to give or assign a form to
> - to give a configuration, form, or design to

> #### [Configure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/configure)
>
> - to set up for operation especially in a particular way.
> - to design or adapt to form a specific configuration or for some specific purpose

**Configure** *should* be used to describe the *formation* of a configuration.

**Configurate** *can* be used to describe the *assignment* of a configuration.

It should be noted that **configurate** is a back-formation of **configure**.

---

Given the little context you've given us, it appears the email did incorrectly use *configurate*. If you'd include the entire text with the question we would know for sure but it does appear they did mean **configured**, instead.

Comment: For **configurate**, the full OED says the sense *To frame by construction, to fashion, shape; to give a configuration to* is ***now rare*** (they give 3 more definitions, all marked as ***obsolete***). I think most (primarily IT-based) instances in recent years are simply misuses.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, I don't have access to the full OED :/ I only answered because I felt the need to defend the fact that **configurate** *can* be used and is not non-existant, despite the possibility of being obsolete.

Comment: I didn't think it was likely you'd have a $200 subscription to OED (I can only use it because my public library provides free access here in the UK). But really, when you compare the current relative prevalence of [configurating,configuring](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=configurating%2Cconfiguring&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconfigurating%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconfiguring%3B%2Cc0), I think the implication is simply that a small number of people are misusing an obsolete term.

Answer (score 1):

I can find no entry for “***configurated***” in any on-line dictionary. The correct word is “***configured***”.

Comment: Did you look hard? I found one after simply googling the word.

Comment: @Hank - How about a link to that alleged dictionary? Googling "define configurated" got me nothing, and insisted that I must mean "configuration".

Comment: See my answer. I have linked two.